# How to use regular expression in Java to match multiple or single values in single or multiple square brackets?

Tags: java, regex, string, tdd, calculator

I am trying to complete Roy Osherove's String Calculator as a TDD exercise and as the inputs have a pattern, i thought I would use a regex, but its something I have not used much in Java.

The two inputs I am testing are : `String string = "//[***]\n1***2***3"` and `String string = "//[*][%]\\n1*2%3"`.

Valid inputs are :

1. `//[***]\n1***2***3`
2. `//;\n1;2`
3. `//[%%]\n1%%2%%3`
4. `//[*][%]\\n1*2%3`

I have managed to create an expression that matches the first input : `Boolean matches = Pattern.compile("//(\\[(\\D+)])+\n.*").matcher(string).matches();`

The issue is when I try to match the second string, I use the following, but does not seem to match : `Boolean matches = Pattern.compile("//(\\[(\\D+)]+)+\\n.*").matcher(string).matches();`

Any help is greatly appreciated to better understand where I am going wrong, The object is everything between `\\` and `\n` can be used as delimiters for the text after '\n'.

Comment: Please add some clear sample input data, and then point out what you are trying to match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have amended to add viable inputs that will be used and elaborated on the meaning behind the patterns.